# Flutter : I'm trying to fetch api data into listview , got that error " type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index' "

Tags: flutter

Hi all I'm new in Flutter , I'm trying to fetch api data into listview , got the following error
type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'  ,
type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'
type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'
don't know what to do .
thanks in advance .

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  Future<List<User>> getData() async {
    var data = await http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos");
    var jsonData = json.decode(data.body);

    List<User> users = [];
    for (var u in jsonData.) {
      User user = new User(u["title"], u["userId"], u["completed"], u["id"]);
      users.add(user);
    }
    print(users.length);
    return users;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Api Calling'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: getData(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.data == null) {
              return Container(
                child: Text("data loading"),
              );
            } else {
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text("${snapshot.data["index"].id}"),
                  );
                },
              );
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class User {
  final int userId;
  final int id;
  final String title;
  final bool completed;
  User(this.title, this.userId, this.completed, this.id);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be do like this: "index" (String type) -> index (Int type)

```
title: Text("${snapshot.data[index].id}"),
```

Answer (score 0):

In `ListView.builder`

Try changing `"index"` to `index`..

Here..

```dart
title: Text("${snapshot.data["index"].id}"),
```

Change it to..

```dart
title: Text("${snapshot.data[index].id}"),
```

Reason:
The index of an array (list) should be of type `int`.. however, when you put it in quotes(" ")..that will be treated as `string` and that is what causing your error..

Hopefully, it should work and your issue will be solved..feel free to ask for clarification :)

Comment: Thank u so much for the solution and clarification